# django-imagekit refuses to upscale an image

Tags: python, django, django-imagekit

I'm having some issues with ImageKit. When an image is submitted through the admin forms, I want it to be resized to a specific size (320x450). My current configuration is the following:

```
imagen = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='tapas',
           processors=[ResizeToFit(width=320, height=450, upscale=True)],
           format='JPEG',
           options={'quality': 80},
           null = True,
           blank = True)
```

This is working perfectly when the image submitted is bigger than the required size, but it keeps the image unaltered for smaller ones. I have also tried to set `mat_color`  but this is not working neither. I could not find documentation of which format should mat_color received, but I have tried with `255`, `(255,255,255)`, and `(255,255,255,0)` with no luck.

I would appreciate if you can guide me to a solution for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was weird... It was some environment issue. I set up a new virtualenv, install the packages again and everything started working fine.